# How to get local time of different time zones?

Tags: java, timezone

I want to get local time of different time zones using Java code. Based on the time zone passed to the function I need that time zone's local time. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
java.util.TimeZone tz = java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1");
java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(tz);

System.out.println(c.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+c.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get(java.util.Calendar.SECOND));
```

Comment: This code failed on me so instead I used cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, rawOffset) and did required timezone calculations myself to be independent from timezone IDs. See @Subhamay answer.

Comment: Echoing @Constain Zagorsky's comment, this solution does give the correct, adjusted HOUR, MINUTE & SECOND - but milliseconds (`c.getTimeInMillis()`) always returns GMT.

Answer (score 15):

I'd encourage you to check out Joda Time, an alternative (but very popular) to the standard Java date and time API:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html

Using Joda Time, I think this is what you what:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

public class TimeZoneDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis(), DateTimeZone.forID("UTC"));
    System.out.println("Current time is: " + now);
  }
}
```

You just need to know the standard ID for the time zone in question, such as UTC.

Comment: Thanks for the Response . I am writing a small class and I don't want to import joda package for this small class. Can you suggest any other way ? Thanks again

Answer (score 11):

Java 1.8 provides you with some new classes in package `java.time`:

```java
package learning.java8;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import org.junit.Test;

public class JavaTimeLT {

    @Test
    public void zonedDataTimeExample() {
        final ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich");
        final ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), zoneId);
        System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the following program to get time for all the Timezones available, see if this helps...

```
String[] zoneIds = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
    for (int i = 0; i < zoneIds.length; i++) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneIds[i]);
    System.out.print(tz.getID() + " " + tz.getDisplayName());
        Calendar calTZ = new GregorianCalendar(tz);
        calTZ.setTimeInMillis(new Date().getTime());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, calTZ.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, calTZ.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calTZ.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calTZ.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calTZ.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, calTZ.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, calTZ.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    System.out.println( "  "+cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 3):

check this. hope it will help.

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    int LocalOffSethrs = (int) ((cal.getTimeZone().getRawOffset()) *(2.77777778 /10000000));

    int ChinaOffSethrs = (int) ((tz.getRawOffset()) *(2.77777778 /10000000));

    TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central");
    String ss =cal.getTimeZone().getDisplayName();

    System.out.println("Local Time Zone : " + ss);
    System.out.println("China Time : " + tz.getRawOffset());

    System.out.println("Local Offset Time from GMT: " + LocalOffSethrs);
    System.out.println("China Offset Time from GMT: " + ChinaOffSethrs);

    cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND,-(cal.getTimeZone().getRawOffset()));
    //cal.add(Calendar.HOUR,- LocalOffSethrs);

    cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, tz.getRawOffset());
    Date dt = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());                  
    System.out.println("After adjusting offset Acctual China Time :" + dt);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8, you can use the [`ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) method:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"));
LocalTime localTime = zonedDateTime.toLocalTime();

System.out.println(localTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Seoul"));
GregorianCalendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);

System.out.println(dateFormat.format( cal.getTime()));
```