# Change timezones based on time of day

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been looking for the last week for a java code that will show me where in the world is 9 o'clock in the morning, and what timezone. Any help with this will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With fairly low effort you could get the time in all timezones, or just quickly calculate how many hours to add/subtract from the local timezone to determine which one is 9AM based on the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156156/how-to-get-local-time-of-different-timezones).

You could then create a small map of timezone to list of cities and pick one from the list.

`Map<String, List<String>> timezoneToCities = new HashMap<>();
timezoneToCities.put("GMT+1", Arrays.asList("Paris", "Madrid"));`

Unfortunately places move in and out of timezones at various times of the year, so it would be quite difficult to keep track.